# ?author=0 keeps accessible (wordpress). What is this template?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I can't get http://www.mywebsite.com/?author=0 unaccessible. I'm aware of different type of standard templates WordPress provides us with. So I use the following code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'page_template_redirect');
function page_template_redirect(){
        global $wp_query, $post;

        if (is_archive()){

                wp_redirect(get_option('home'));
                exit;

        }

}
```

This should redirect all author archives, category pages, taxonomy pages etc. to my home. I'm not building a blog so I don't want these pages to show up in Google. I'm also building a template which should be re-usable, so I want everything to work on template-level. Best is no manual htaccess edits.

It blocks all my author pages like /author/ and /?author=1, but it doesn't block the /?author=0 page. It shows a list with all my posts from my index.php (which I'm not using since I'm using a custom homepage template). is_author() or is_archive() result in 'false'.

Where does this page come from and how can I prevent that it shows up in Google? I would like to configure it from my theme to redirect or 404.

Comment: try `add_filter( 'template_include', 'page_template_redirect', 99 );` and inplace of wp_redirect use `include( get_template_directory() . '/search.php' );`

Comment: Well, that causes two things to change:
- instead of redirecting to home all my author/archive templates redirect to the search template. That's better for google results I guess.
- but /?author=0 now results in a white page. There seems to went something wrong..

Comment: Can you post new code ?

Comment: It just seems no template is being included when ?author=0 page is triggered.. No added class to body too.

Comment: In place of include try `return`  , I have learned recently using include is a bad idea, may be the same case .